# Post-build Event error visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

what's wrong with this post-build event? I want to copy the entire contents of a resources folder over to the target directory while maintaining the but it keeps exiting with code 1:

copy $(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\Resources*.* $(TargetDir)Resources\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check the output window and see what the command results in after all the $(...) expansions?  Post that

Comment: Does the target directory exist? Why don't you use MSBuild's CopyTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
xcopy /Y $(ProjectDir)Resources\*.* $(TargetDir)Resources\
```

That is probably the most robust as it will also create the directory for you if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks everyone; I'll try this one out...forgot all about xcopy I'll post  back if it works. Just got engulfed in a bigger fire :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not running from the directory you think it's running from.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy /Y $(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\Resources*.* $(TargetDir)Resources\